# China to Cayman Islands via Miami

Tags: air-travel, transit

One of my friends is going to the Cayman Islands for work, and she got approved for a visa from the UK... but she wants to take a flight from China to Miami to Cayman because the air ticket is cheaper. So is it possible?

Comment: Is she a Chinese national? If so, she would need a US visa for the Miami connection. There is no airside transit without visa in the United States.

Comment: It is possible, provided he/she has a visa for the US. If not, apply for a transit visa.